# scheme recursive function list overrides

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket

I'm trying to do a recursive function that gets a list of string-int pairs + a string named prefix, and using function named "starts-with" it sums up all the ints whose begininng match the prefix. 
Problem is, I can never get the list to go forward, it gets stuck at the beginning and then program crashes.

```
(define (sum-of-pairs-start-with prefix ls)
    ( let*(  (prefix2 (string->list prefix))
          (str2 (string->list (car (car ls)))))
(cond((null? str2) 0)   
     ( (starts-with prefix (car(car ls))) 
       (+  cdr(car ls) (sum-of-pairs-start-with prefix (cdr ls))) ) 
     (else sum-of-pairs-start-with prefix (cdr ls))) ) )
```

I work with input:

```
(sum-of-pairs-start-with "a" (list (cons "a" 1) (cons "b" 2) (cons "aa" 33) (cons "ca" 4))) ;; =34
```

but once i get to the second pair in the list ("b" 2) it goes to the else condition as expected, but then ls gets back up one line to origin (with the previous value) instead of going forward to next value ("aa" 33).
I 'm new to scheme and I dont get why that happens, it's frustrating

Comment: First, get rid of all the syntax errors.

Comment: which syntax errors? racket's compiler didnt mention any..

Comment: Well, there are syntax errors, and there are _syntax errors_. Compare these two expressions: `(list (+ 1 2))` and `(list + 1 2)`. The compiler or interpreter will not complain about the second one because it is a perfectly legal expression. It is also almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: How are you seeing it "back up"? I get "+: constract violation ..." in Racket. (As expected, by the way; you're trying to add `cdr`, `(car ls)`, and the recursive result.)

Comment: I see it on Debug mode, it's in the "else" line and then gets right back to the line above it

Answer (score 2):

You just have to call the `starts-with` procedure that we previously defined (let it take care of converting the strings to char lists), and fix *all of the syntax problems*:

```
(define (sum-of-pairs-start-with prefix ls)
  (cond ((null? ls) 0)   
        ((starts-with prefix (car (car ls)))
         (+ (cdr (car ls)) (sum-of-pairs-start-with prefix (cdr ls))))
        (else (sum-of-pairs-start-with prefix (cdr ls)))))
```

Once again, you're having trouble invoking the procedures. For example, these snippets are wrong:

```
cdr(car ls)
(else sum-of-pairs-start-with prefix (cdr ls))
```

Please, grab a book on Scheme and practice the basic syntax, remember that procedures are *not* called like this: `f(x)`, the correct way is `(f x)`. Also, pay attention to the correct way to indent the code, it'll be easier to find the errors if you follow the conventions.

Comment: Lopez believe me I am doing my best, watching it on youtube and stuff, but I just dont get it.. and I've already solved this one by myself, but I still have a lot of questions

Comment: @mooly I know you're trying, and I commend your efforts :-) , but it'd be a good idea to spend more time getting acquainted with the basic syntax and solving simpler problems, before tackling harder challenges. Some nice books to get started: "The Little Schemer", "How to Design Programs".

Comment: @mooly Both [How to Design Programs](http://htdp.org/) and [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)  (not quite as beginner-friendly, but very good) are freely available online. Books are better than youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a solution using higher functions:

```
(define (sum-of-pairs-start-with prefix ls)
  (apply +
         (map cdr
              (filter (λ (x) (starts-with prefix (car x)))
                      ls))))
```

It filters out those sublists which have prefix in first item, then gets second item (cdr) from each of those sublists and finally applies add function to all of them.